# Transforming nested XML elements to equal parent element; remove parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of XML that looks as follows:

```
<LISTOFHARDWARE>
    <HARDWARE>
        <item>
            <SERIALNUMBER>D4242050101</SERIALNUMBER>
            <STATUS>2 </STATUS>
            <STATUSREASON>998 </STATUSREASON>
            <MACADDRESS />
            <LINKEDSMARTCARD>4135237101</LINKEDSMARTCARD>
            <PRODUCTDETAIL>
                <TYPE>DEVICE</TYPE>
                <MODEL>ABC123</MODEL>
            </PRODUCTDETAIL>
        </item>
        <item>
            <SERIALNUMBER>D4242050101</SERIALNUMBER>
            <STATUS>2 </STATUS>
            <STATUSREASON>998 </STATUSREASON>
            <MACADDRESS />
            <LINKEDSMARTCARD>4135237101</LINKEDSMARTCARD>
            <PRODUCTDETAIL>
                <TYPE>DEVICE</TYPE>
                <MODEL>ABC123</MODEL>
            </PRODUCTDETAIL>
        </item>
    </HARDWARE>
</LISTOFHARDWARE>
```

I would like the `<item>` elements to be replaced by `<HARDWARE>` elements (the immediate parent element), and the parent `<HARDWARE>` element to be removed, so that the result looks as follows:

```
<LISTOFHARDWARE>
    <HARDWARE>
        <SERIALNUMBER>D4242050101</SERIALNUMBER>
        <STATUS>2 </STATUS>
        <STATUSREASON>998 </STATUSREASON>
        <MACADDRESS />
        <LINKEDSMARTCARD>4135237101</LINKEDSMARTCARD>
        <PRODUCTDETAIL>
            <TYPE>DEVICE</TYPE>
            <MODEL>ABC123</MODEL>
        </PRODUCTDETAIL>
    </HARDWARE>
    <HARDWARE>
        <SERIALNUMBER>D4242050101</SERIALNUMBER>
        <STATUS>2 </STATUS>
        <STATUSREASON>998 </STATUSREASON>
        <MACADDRESS />
        <LINKEDSMARTCARD>4135237101</LINKEDSMARTCARD>
        <PRODUCTDETAIL>
            <TYPE>DEVICE</TYPE>
            <MODEL>ABC123</MODEL>
        </PRODUCTDETAIL>

    </HARDWARE>
</LISTOFHARDWARE>
```

Is there a way I can do this in an XSL transformation that will work for any XML file that contains `<item>` elements?

**EDIT**

After the help on this answer and a little further research, I am almost there, but not quite. Consider the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  Replace <item> with name of parent element -->
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove immediate parent of <item> elements -->
    <xsl:template match="item/.."> <!-- Results in syntax error --> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that after successful of changing the `<item>` elements to the name of the parent, I cannot remove the parent of any `item` element by referencing its parent dynamically.

Comment: You can't use `..` in a match pattern, instead try `*[item]` (which can be read as "any element which has a child element named `item`").

Comment: However, after I changed <item> to something else in the previous template, surely this one well never match anyway, right? (Thanks for your input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{node-name(.)}">
            <xsl:for-each select="*/item">
                <xsl:element name="{node-name(..)}">
                  <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT BY OP:** For my case, I had to change the function `node-name()` to `name()`, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: This XSLT does not compile for me.

Comment: Ah, it was complaining about the node-name function. When changing it to name, it works. You are a genius!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match=" @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Process any element that has "item" as child -->
  <xsl:template match="*[item]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace "item" with its parent in source XML -->
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks mzjn, but I need this to work anywhere in an XML document where <item> elements crop up, regardless of the name of the parent element (i.e. that part must be dynamic).

Comment: This answer was perfectly correct and even more elegant. I had the same requirement and this solution worked perfectly for me. Also it is very simple compared to the above answer which has it's own inherent complexity due to the use of xslt pull model for the transformation. Really cool answer this is. :)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to learn about the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which can be used to copy all nodes in your XML that don't require any changes

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You need to simplify how you think your transformation is going to work, as all you are really saying is remove the **item** element, but keep its children. TO do this, just another simple template will suffix

```
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

All this is doing is matching the **item** element, but then just continuing processing its children without copying the **item** element itself (and the child nodes just get copied by the identity template).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim. What your solution is doing is resulting in a single <hardware> item with the children of the <item> elements inside, whereas I need the children of the <item> elements to each be surrounded by <hardware> as in my desired outcome above.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread the question. I see **mzjn** has beat me to it though, as he has shown the correct way.

Comment: Sorry, the last line in my question holds a key part of my requirement: I need this to work for any <item> elements, regardless of the name of their parent. How can I make that part dynamic? mzjn's solution will work only if the parent is <HARDWARE>.

Comment: As you see from my updated question, I can successfully rename the <item> elements to the name of the parent element, but removing the parent of any <item> element is problematic.

Comment: Once again, it looks like **mzjn** has beat me to it, as he has updated his question with the syntax you need `<xsl:template match="*[item]">`